# How to get out of the maze using recursion?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

Let's consider a maze represented by a matrix of ints: 0 - not visited, 1 - obstacles (blocked positions), 2 - visited, -1 - output, (x,y) - start position. I want to find a path from start to some output by using recursion.

```
int[] x_dir = new int[] { 0, 0, -1, 1 }; // x, x, x-1, x + 1
int[] y_dir = new int[] { -1, 1, 0, 0 }; // y-1, y+1, y, y

bool dfs(int[,] maze, int x, int y, int[] x_dir, int[] y_dir)
{
   if (maze[x, y] == -1) { return true; } // output cell marked -1 

   int i = 0;
   while (i < 4 && !dfs(maze, x + x_dir[i], y + y_dir[i], x_dir, y_dir))
   {
      ++i;
   }
   return (i > 4) ? false : true;
}
```

I have two problem: I don't know how to handle edge cases(`IndexOutOfRangeException inside maze[x,y]`) and how to print a path.
Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

To print a path, you need to keep track of it, which suggests adding a parameter for that purpose.  Care must be taken to not include wrong turns in it, or at least to remove them once you know that is what they are.

Alternatively, if you print out the step you took for each call to `dfs` that returned `true`, you would have the path, but in reverse.

As for the edge (not corner) cases: you need to check that `x+x_dir[i]` and `y+y_dir[i]` are valid indices into the maze before trying to access those locations in the maze.

Comment: How to print a path by using recursion?

Answer (score 0):

for printing path , you can create an additional matrix and store information in it.Same as in longest subsequence problem solved with dynamic programming.

OR
rather than creating some additional matrix,you can use the same matrix.To keep track of path,just save the state when you find an output cell.

```
while (i < 4)
{ 
    if(!dfs(maze, x + x_dir[i], y + y_dir[i], x_dir, y_dir))
        ++i;
    else
        maze[x][y]=255;
}
```

then follow the cell with elements 255.
Hope this helps.